# How can I stop script execution if insert value is null and set value if not null?

Tags: mysql, case, exec

I have tried to use Case and SET NOEXEC ON but get the following errors:

> Syntax Error: unexpected 'SET' (set)
>   Syntax Error: missing 'closing parenthesis'

```
INSERT INTO tag (table, repr, tag, value)
    SELECT 'product' AS table,
           @Id AS repr,
           'product_code' AS tag,
           CASE @Code       
             WHEN NOT null THEN @Code
             ELSE SET NOEXEC ON
           END AS value`
```

`@Id` and `@Code` are declared parameters in the script

Comment: please tag your question with the DBMS you're using.  Also `'null' <> NULL`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply define the `value` column as `NOT NULL`?  The insert would fail if you tried to `INSERT` a null value into that column.  Also, when you say you want to stop the script, do you mean terminate with an error or simply silently do nothing?

Comment: I cannot alter the column to be NOT NULL. And I want to terminate with an error message if possible

Answer (score 1):

`SET NOEXEC ON` is not MySQL syntax.

The thing to do is to avoid selecting it:

```
INSERT INTO tag (table, repr, tag, value)
    SELECT 'product' AS table,
            @Id AS repr,
            'product_code' AS tag,
            @Code AS value`        -- The WHERE will prevent nulls
        WHERE @Code IS NOT NULL;   -- avoid generating anything to insert when NULL
```

Comment: But this will not stop execution of script, right?

Comment: @DBNewbie - If you need that, we need to see the rest of the Stored Procedure.

Comment: There are more insert statements after this hence would need to stop script execution. Can I use BEGIN and END with exception or catch?

Comment: Maybe something like `IF ( SELECT ROWS_AFFECTED() ) > 0 ) THEN ... (do rest of proc) END;`

Comment: Whenever I use IF, it throws an error:

Comment: @DBNewbie - You are inside a Stored Routine?